# Adsense - "An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later. [or-ieh-01]"

Tags: adsense

My Adsense was working fine since last 7 years. One fine day I tried to change the bank account from Individual to Company bank account. Since then I am getting the error - "An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later. [or-ieh-01].

I have tried-

1. Submitting the valid documents for the new bank account.
2. Reverting to the old working bank account (with the valid document for that account).
3. Deleting both the accounts and then try adding any of the bank account.

Neither of the above worked. Now my earned amount is stuck and I cannot use other Ad providers also as they required Google Ad Manager that is linked with a working Adsense account.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're not the only one. Unluckily this is a [known issue](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/115645430/known-issue-error-message-or-baih-01%E2%80%9D-or-%E2%80%9Cor-ieh-01%E2%80%9D-on-adsense-payment-page?hl=en) since mid-2021 and still unresolved. The cruel truth is, that there seemingly only exists a generic answer to this issue:

1. Try the path described on the [official GooglePay issue fix site](https://support.google.com/googlepay/answer/7644087?hl=en#zippy=%2Ctroubleshoot-verification-issues). Do exactly as demanded and double-check everything. In most cases that will work.
2. If that doesn't work contact the [GooglePay Support](https://support.google.com/pay/gethelp). That's meh but you probably won't have another choice.

Or you might, as written in the official [issue post](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/115645430/known-issue-error-message-or-baih-01%E2%80%9D-or-%E2%80%9Cor-ieh-01%E2%80%9D-on-adsense-payment-page?hl=en), "try to use [another form of payment or bank account](https://support.google.com/pay/answer/7644064?hl=en) for now".

You have my sympathy :-/

---

*Edit:* As mentioned in the comments below further ideas would be:

- In case you're using it, disable VPN while you're using GooglePay as it seems to lead to conflicts.
- Associate a new mail address.

Not sure, how esoteric that is, though. Those ideas came up after talking to friends and some web research.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the different approaches. Have tried all of them multiple times.

Comment: Does the support at least answer to your mail?

Comment: In the case of Adsense support, the only way to connect with them is through Community as of now due to Covid. For Google Pay, they do have chat support but they have no clue about the issue and they simply say to connect with Adsense.

Comment: I did some research in the last days, asking friends and browsing the web. The only two additional ideas I can provide are (1) In case you're using it, disable VPN while you're using GooglePay as it seems to lead to conflicts. (2) Associate a new mail address (not sure whether this is really a good idea). Otherwise it's more or less always the same recommendations which you seem to have already followed. And also people regularily complain about the GooglePay support.

Comment: Interestingly I got the (subjective) impression, that people from South- and South-East-Asia are affected unproportionally frequent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling adblocker and trying again?

Comment: Not sure, how adblocker is related to AdSense payment issue. Aso as a matter of fact, I don't use any ad blocker.

Comment: Some adblockers block adsense api and subdomains completely, blocking the xhr request to the server